# Creating instagram access token generator

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I wanted to create a simple Instagram access token generator that can be used by any user. Something like this:

> http://instagram.pixelunion.net/

Now I am able to create a simple access token generator like that using some cURL in php and this

> https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Though the issue is, this access token generator works for the user whose app credentials are used in php and who are included as sandbox user to this client, for all other users it is showing this.

```
{"code": 403, "error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException", "error_message": "You are not a sandbox user of this client"}
```

Can anyone say what should I do for a generic access token generator

Screenshot of my app:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I am able to achieve what I desired.

The reason for it was the app needed to be submitted for review. Though at first it got rejected, as it requires a video url showing what this app really want to achieve and how it is doing that. So, I created a video corresponding to all work and submitted again, it got approved and finally the code work as expected.

Here is an output of that:

> http://webkul.com/instatoken/

If anyone feels to ask anything about it, they can ask it here.

I have used following use case for permission review:

[image]

Comment: Hi, which use case did you choose for your access token generator? Any detailed information would be really helpful. I'm also trying to get my access token generator approved with no luck.

Comment: @SodbilegGansukh I have edited my answer, check it. Also, I have briefly explained in API use case that what my app intends to do, and do provide a 'Video Screencast URL'

Comment: What PHP you have behind this? http://webkul.com/instatoken/

I want to create a token generator on my own website but no idea how to.
Thanks

Comment: @rjpedrosa that contains a cURL hit to `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token` with parameters `'client_id', 'client_secret', 'grant_type', 'redirect_uri' and 'code'`. This will produce a JSON encoded result with token. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are not a sandbox user, thats the reason it is failing, use the account used to create developer account to login and that should work.

The example website you have posted is reviewed and live, so any user can login. You are in sandbox mode.

Comment: I have just added a screenshot of my app. Can you please say, what should I do?

Comment: login with the user that is signed-in in the screenshot

Comment: ok, i think i have to submit that app for it to be usable by any other user. I have already done that at instagram. Let see if they approve and then it worked